# Comfy Mexican Sofa snippet content not being accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, haml, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I'm very new to using Comfy CMS and I can't seem to get this simple helper method to work.
I am creating a carousel and I want the Comfy CMS to provide me the images to place in the carousel.

```
#pcs_carousel.carousel.slide
  .carousel-inner
    #0.item.active
      %img{:alt => "Temp Image", :src => "#{cms_snippet_content('homepage_carousel')}"}
  %a.left.carousel-control{:href => "#pcs_carousel", "data-slide" =>"prev"}
  %a.right.carousel-control{:href => "#pcs_carousel", "data-slide" =>"next"}
```

Am I using cms_snippet_content() improperly in my view? I looked at the Comfy CMS wiki but it just tells me to use that method to access content from my snippets. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Snippets only deal with text content. Where is the image coming from? Do you just have url as snippet content? Very unusual.

Honestly, you probably want to create a normal crud to manage carousel images. Paperclip, and all. There's technically: https://github.com/comfy/comfy-gallery but it's not working with current CMS. Really need to rewrite that.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I got it to work by handling things in the controller better and was able to just have the url as snippet content but like you had mentioned it was an unusual method but I only did it because it wasn't rendering properly. However, I soon found out that it wasn't rendering because of html_safe missing so now I have my html as my snippet content and everything works.